# website is not loading home page (moving from one server to another server)

Tags: customization, multisite, htaccess, homepage, settings-api

I have a wordpress site and i want same site with other domain name at same server. I moved all files and folders to new domains directory and also successfully moved database. My admin panel is working fine but when i enter url of homepage , it does not load homepage as you can see in image[image: enter url and all files are showing]
I also chane url of site and home from database. what can be a issue? and also i am getting an error from site health screen and all other things are working properly. any solution guys?

> The Rest API encountered an unexpected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be missing some files. There should be an `index.php` file in that root directory for example. Try downloading a fresh copy of WordPress from http://wordpress.org/wordpress-5.6-no-content.zip and upload the files from that zip to your new server

Comment: you were right, Index.php file was missing . Thanks for your Help :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to update the URLs in the database, I run the following sql query in phpmyadmin > database > query after a migration.

swap `wp_` with your db table prefix if different from default, & adjust any URLs as needed:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'oldurl.com','newurl.com');
```